# Why Pkgbuild Relocates the .app

Tags: ios, macos, package, packagemaker, pkgbuild

Can any one help me..........

I tried to create a package using pkgbuild. It creates the package properly and installation is also works fine, but when we saw the installation location everything is copied except .app.

Installation log shown .app relocate to some "xxxxxx" foder.

If we delete that "xxxxxx" folder and install it shows .app relocate to some "yyyyyy" folder.

When we make the package manually we uncheck the "allow relocate" option for .app. I stuck with doing same thing through pkgbuild command.

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/19283889/151502 ?