# How to Force install location from OSX .pkg

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, pkgbuild

I'm attempting to create a package installer for our product. Previously we installed with a .dmg, and the process was to just drag it to the /Applications folder. Now we want it to install to /Application/Company/Suite/product.

Problem is: If we use the .pkg installer on a system that previously had our product installed it creates the folders, but installs the product over the old location.

How can I make the pkg installer do the following:

1. Remove the old version
2. Install new version to proper location

I've had very little experience with OSX - so maybe I'm just missing something? Also looking in the applications folder - it doesn't appear that anything else is installed to a subdirectory, is it unusual to do things this way?
Thank you!

EDIT:
I'm looking into the answers located here [OSX .pkg installer sometimes does not install .app file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283889/osx-pkg-installer-sometimes-does-not-install-app-file), differently worded problem - but the answer might be just what I need.

EDIT2: [OSX .pkg installer sometimes does not install .app file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283889/osx-pkg-installer-sometimes-does-not-install-app-file) Does not apply. We didn't install with any package manager - so there isn't a previous entry.

EDIT3: We were using **dmg**, but are now moving to **pkg**.

Comment: It is unusual. Unless you have extenuating circumstances, please just distribute an app, and possibly a drag to applications .dmg thingie.

Comment: The decision is pretty high above me, but if OSX really doesn't do things this way - I'll pass that info up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer.

In order to have it install to a new location:
   The plist inside the app package (product.app/Contents/Info.plist) has an identifier "CFBundleIdentifier", these needs to be different from the old application. For instance ours was "Company.Product-Name", I've changed it to "Company.Product.Name". This will allow the new installation to go to the new location.

In order to remove the old installation:
   I simply added this line to the preinstall script:
   "sudo rm -Rf '/Application/Product Name.app'"

Thank you for your assistance.